# Using host command to call a url with parameters in Oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle, host

I am using Forms [32 Bit] Version 6.0.8.26.0

Within a Oracle Forms trigger I am using the host command to call a url with parameters. An example of this part of my code is below:

```
HOST('cmd /c start http://localhost/TestServlet?p1=A&p2=B');
```

but the browser is invoked with output url that is showing till the ampersand sign and stops:

```
http://localhost/TestServlet?p1=A
```

Any suggestions on how to get the full url using the HOST command from oracle forms

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `&` with `%26` inside URL

Comment: No that doesn't work, but I found the closest solution for displaying the full url string is the use of double quotes in the command, but this providing the full string including the double quotes which makes again a problem. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I found the closest solution for displaying the full url string is the use of double quotes in the command, but it seems not useful for url and suitable only for string s becuase using this method is providing me the full string url but that includes the double quotes which makes again a problem. 
`HOST('cmd /c start http://localhost/TestServlet?p1=A"&p2=B"');`
and the output
`http://localhost/TestServlet?p1=A"&p2=B"`

Note that double quotes are included in the URL

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: **How do I escape an ampersand in a url?**

Comment: @user2079954 - Simply type `HOST('cmd /c start http://localhost/TestServlet?p1=A%26p2=B');` - this is the standard way to escape any problematic symbols in URL.  Doesn't it work?

Comment: I tried using the `%26` but the problem is its not identified by the target servlet, however I managed the ampersand issue using escape symbol `^&^` another issue here is in the parameter contains string I enclosed the string with double quotes it works but the double quotes are removing the internal spaces within the string ???

Answer (score 0):

`&` is used to separate commands. Therefore we can use `^` to escape the `&`

Answer (score 0):

replace spaces by %20 and use ^&

Answer (score 0):

Try losing the "cmd /c".

This worked for me:

```
PROCEDURE call_url_from_forms6i(i_user_id           varchar2
                               ,i_section_id        varchar2) is
  /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320620/using-host-command-to-call-a-url-with-parameters-in-oracle-forms */                               
  p_user_id      varchar2(200) := '&P_USER_ID='||nvl(i_user_id,'1');
  p_section_id   varchar2(200) := '&P_SECTION_ID='||nvl(i_section_id, '0');
  p_report_name  varchar2(200) := '&report_name=REPNAME';  
  p_url         varchar2(200) := 'http://website.com/folder/';
  v_servlet_name varchar2(200) := 'servletname?';
  p_report       varchar2(200) := 'report=REPORT';    
  p_url_hdr      varchar2(200) := p_url||v_servlet_name;
  p_url_params   varchar2(2000);
  p_url_host_call varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  p_url_params := p_report||p_user_id||p_section_id||p_report_name;
  --display in browser
  p_url_host_call := 'start "" "'||p_url_hdr||p_url_params||'"';
  host(p_url_host_call);
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --message('Error running report in browser: '||sqlerrm);pause;
    return;
END;
```